# Why is the CLR's jmp instruction unverifiable?

Tags: c#, clr, cil

I've known about the jmp instruction for awhile, but it never struck me as being even remotely unsafe. I recently had cause to check the CIL specs and [was very surprised to discover jmp is considered unverifiable](http://higherlogics.blogspot.com/2010/05/cil-verification-and-safety.html).

Comment: Would this be because it could not verify the impact of execution of the current partially code block then stitched to the destination code block ...

Something about stacks / heap tracking seems to flag in my little dreamworld ... not that I know this for sure though ... however that is immediatly offset by the information here ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.jmp.aspx 
... which clearly states that no stack information is tracked / transferred.

Maybe there's something underneath the "front end" that goes on here that Microsoft is hiding.

Comment: I don't know why it's unverifiable, but I do have an interesting piece of info. Our EQATEC Profiler collects anonymous statistics about all the code it profiles (using EQATEC Analytics, btw). Because jmp was tricky and not handled optimally by the profiler we decided to track how often it actually occurred. We now have 2 years of data, collected from over 1 million profiled assemblies, totalling 20 billion CIL instructions. Quite a lot. And how many were jmp? None! Yes, a jmp has never occurred in any of our user's apps (NETCF, SL, WP7, F# etc). Quite a surprise.

Comment: I'm not too surprised actually. No compiler I know of except perhaps managed C++ emits the jmp instruction, because it's unverifiable. Any uses of jmp might be squirreled away in the trusted class libraries.

Comment: I know it's more than a year ago, but +1 to the questioner. I ran into this while searching for statistics on CIL instructions. And though it doesn't answer my question, it certainly increased my knowledge. Excellent question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, unlike a `call`, `callvirt`, or `calli`, where the caller's stack frame would remain on the stack to be seen by future code access security stackwalks triggered (perhaps indirectly) by the callee, a `jmp` instruction tears down the caller's stack frame prior to transitioning into the callee and is thus invisible to any CAS stackwalks that the callee may trigger.

**Edit: I think naasking is right about the answer above being wrong.** I now think the difference between (verifiable) tail.call sequences and (unverifiable) jmp sequences may be that a tail call requires pushing the arguments to the call onto the evaluation stack where they can be verified in the normal way, whereas a `jmp` requires the evaluation stack to be empty and causes the jump-ee to inherit the arguments of the jump-er. There was probably no reason to complicate the verifier to check `jmp` instructions, but it might be possible to do so under conditions similar to those imposed on `tail.call` sequences (one of which is that the caller and callee must be in the same assembly, which rules out my CAS guess above, at least up to explicit `.Deny( )` calls).

If so, this would be the relevant part of the spec: (Partition III, Section 3.37)

> The current arguments are transferred
>   to the destination method.
>
> The evaluation stack must be empty
>   when this instruction is executed. The
>   calling convention, number and type of
>   arguments at the destination address
>   must match that of the current method.

Comment: While reasonable at first blush, this doesn't stand up to closer scrutiny. The .tailcall prefix has roughly the same behaviour, albeit more general, but .tailcall is verifiable. The documentation simply states that .tailcall is ignored when calling from untrusted to trusted code. If this is the reason jmp is unverifiable, I don't see why they wouldn't have just used the same behaviour for jmp.

Comment: I think "Rodrigo Kumpera" who posted on the linked blog page has it right: if any of the arguments are by-ref, then you can store a reference to a local then execute a jmp. A control flow analysis is required to ensure this does not occur, albeit a relatively simple one. I'd wager they just didn't want to bother since jmp was added mainly to support C++. The same danger exists for .tailcall, so I'm not sure how that's handled, ie. unverifiable, or .tailcall ignored. I'll have to test it at some point.